Where can I meet Vedic rishis?
Where can I meet vedic rishis who are not associated with advaita dvaita or vishishtadvaita? Who teach purely Vedic teachings directly and not associated with any bhasyas..are there any such gurus/rishis in himalayas?

Vedic philosophy is  Adwitha correct? If you understand Bengali. I will suggest videos of Sri Nrisingha Bhaduri. He is an expert in Vedas / Purans and Upanishads.

I dont think Vedic philosophy is Advaita nor is it Achintya Bhedabheda..
